# Find all the roots of equation whether real or complex

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

$$f(x)=(x^4 +7x^3 +22x^2 + 31x + 9)^8$$
Find all the roots of the equation, given $-2+\sqrt5i$  is a root to this equation $f(x)$.

Comment: Presumably the first term is $X^4$, not $X^2$?

Comment: Yess I don't I typed 4

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about roots of polynomials that you think may be helpful?

Comment: @chandsureja You didn't type $4$, check the history.

Comment: I tried dividing the polynomial by its factor so I end up with a cubic equation..

Comment: I think now it's correct

Comment: If $-2+\sqrt5i$ solves the equation, so does $-2-\sqrt5i$.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that, for a polynomial with real coefficients, if $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a root, then $\overline{z}$ is also a root. At your case, $z = -2+i\sqrt{5}$ is known to be a root. Then divide the fourth degree polynomial by $(x-z)(x-\overline{z})$, from whence you obtain a second degree equation. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Wait I understand you but is it necessary that if z is a root then conjugate of z will be a solution to the polynomial.

Comment: In the case where the polynomial's coefficients are real and $z$ is complex, such result holds.

Comment: What about whole power of polynomial which raised by 8. Does that increase number of roots of our polynomial or not

Comment: Given an arbitrary polynomial $f(x)$, the following equivalences hold:

$$[f(x)]^{8} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow |f(x)| = 0 \Longleftrightarrow f(x) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

First, since $0^8= 0$ and, conversely, if $x^8= 0$, x= 0, any x is a root of $(x^4+ 7x^3+ 22x^2+ 31x+ 9)^2= 0$ is a root of $x^4+ 7x^3+ 22x^2+ 31x+ 9= 0$.  Further, since all coefficients are real numbers, given that $-2+ i\sqrt{5}$, $-2- i\sqrt{5}$ is also.  So $(x+ 2- i\sqrt{5})(x+ 2+ i\sqrt{5})= x^2+ 4x+ 4+ 5= x^2+ 4x+ 9$ is a factor.  Dividing $x^4+ 7x^3+ 22x^2+ 31x+ 9$ by $x^2+ 4x+ 4+ 5= x^2+ 4x+ 9$ gives you a quadratic equation you can solve for the other two roots.